# Rest application on home button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want app upgraded to 4.0 to exit completely when home button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268182/want-app-upgraded-to-4-0-to-exit-completely-when-home-button-pressed)

When the user closes the app with the home button,  how can I make the app reload with the splash screen and not where they last left the application.

So it as if they are opening the application for the first tim each time as I would like them to be presented with the intro view which has options all the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, iOS4.0has multi-tasking feature(i.e.,) to run your apps in background.. To stop your XCode application running in the background, open info.plist in your application .

Right click -> Add Row -> Select "Application does not run in the Background" option
Make sure to check the checkbox, right side to it.

I hope this should help you.

Comment: Thanks for this its just the results I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You could release all view in method that would be called when user presses home button:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     */
}
```

Here you can pop all view to your initial view.

Or you can do the same in next method:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can go about this as far as I know;

- If your application does not need to support going to background and resuming, you can disable this through the application plist. Then the app will do a fresh start everytime.
- When the app goes to the background and comes back, the method `applicationDidBecomeActive:` will be called. You can write any code here which will always direct the user to the intro screen you desire.

Check the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.